# Floating left all elements in a row inside floated right parent

Tags: css, css-float, floating

Here's my issue: http://jsfiddle.net/4f4Laskz/2/

I just want to make all list items as inside a row. But the last element doesn't stay at the right and goes downside of row. Why it happens?

HTML:

```
<a href="#index" class="logo">
    <h1><span class="medikal">Some text</span></h1>
    <span class="saglik">Some text</span>
</a>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="selected"><a href="#hakkimizda">Some text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#urunler">Some text</a></li>
        <li><a href="#markalar">Some text</a></li>                                  
        <li><a href="#iletisim">Some text</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.logo {
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    float: left;
    line-height: 0.2em;
}

nav {
    margin: 0.7em 0;
    float: right;
    font-size: 16px;
}

nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 1%;
    border-radius: 5px;     
}
```

Comment: One way to solve this is fixing the width of `nav`.

Comment: @xyres, we don't know about how many elements will add to nav. Sum of total element's width can be higher than fixed nav's. And we don't want it. Look at solution of Christian Varga above, it works perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Floated elements without widths are highly unpredictable and should be avoided if at all possible.

A floated element is generally as wide as its children. Using percentages for children inside floated elements confuses the renderer.

Think about it: a percentage padding on the children requires the renderer to know the width of the parent. But the width of the floated parent is based off the sum width of all its children (including their padding). So this type of calculation is complicated chicken-or-egg scenario, and it appears that the renderer just gives up and does something weird instead.

Try using non-percentage values instead:

```
nav li {
    margin: 0 10px;
    float: left;
    padding: 6px;
    border-radius: 5px;     
}
```

Comment: Awesome explanation. Didn't know about *"without margins"* thing.

Comment: It works, thank you! And i didn't set a width for them because of issue possibilities for higher letter countings.

Comment: No worries. I think I'm wrong about the width issue now that I've done some more testing. Removing the margins definitely fixes it, but the nav actually is wide enough to handle 4 elements. So I don't know why it's wigging out.

Comment: Sorry guys, I was completely wrong. But I have determined the real issue and updated my post to reflect the updated findings.

Comment: Yep, this make more sence than other. Percentage padding makes parent width higher, and childs padding also getting higher because of parent, and parents width getting more higher... It's like an infinite loop.

Thanks again!